# Aerospike Parameter Error when appending to list

Tags: aerospike, aerospike-ce

```
        WritePolicy writePolicy = new WritePolicy();
        writePolicy.expiration = ttl;
        Key keyObject = new Key(aerospikeNamespace, aerospikeSetName, key);
        com.aerospike.client.Value value =  com.aerospike.client.Value.get(sessionId);
        ListPolicy listPolicy = new ListPolicy(ListOrder.UNORDERED, ListWriteFlags.ADD_UNIQUE | ListWriteFlags.NO_FAIL);
        aerospikeClient.operate(writePolicy, keyObject, ListOperation.append(listPolicy, bin, value, null));
```

Giving Exception : com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error 4,1,30000,0,0,XXXXXXXXXXX XX.XXX.XX.XXX 3000: Parameter error

**Also, it is working for some of the keys and giving this exception for other keys. Using aerospike cluster and all nodes are up and connected**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are all the Aerospike nodes installed with same version?

"Illegal parameter sent from client. Check client parameters and verify each is supported by current server version." - Parameter Error notes from the Aerospike error codes documentation (https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/dev_reference/error_codes.html).

I suspect that the nodes that doesn't encounter this exception are using a supported server version for the operation you're trying to execute and the others don't. If thats the case upgrading all the nodes Aerospike server's version to align with the latest (in the current cluster) will solve it.

Comment: Yes, version is not same for all the nodes in the cluster. Two of the servers are on version 3.15.1.4 and one is on version 4.5.1.4.

Comment: I believe you are using a feature that isn't supported on Aerospike Server 3.15.1.4, Running your operation on the nodes with 3.15.1.4 will fail with the Parameter Error you mentioned, I suggest upgrading both remaining nodes to be aligned with the 4.5.1.4 node if you want to use this operation.

Comment: Thanks Roi. As per their documentation (https://docs.aerospike.com/docs/guide/operations/list/insert.html) NO_FAIL feature is supported since 4.3.0